# For which $n$ does there exist a surjective homomorphism from $SL_n(\mathbf{R})\rightarrow PGL_n(\mathbf{R})$?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-homomorphism, infinite-groups

Also, how does the situation change when replacing $\mathbf{R}$ with $\mathbf{Q}$?

I have only very basic tools to approach this problem. My attempt at understanding it is that $PGL_n$ is the set of linear transformations which leave the norms of vectors the same, while $SL_n$ is the set of linear transformations which preserve volumes and their orientations. But I must have some misunderstanding because then one could consider in $PGL_4$ the matrix

$$\left(\begin{array}{cccc}-1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0  &0 \\ 0& 0&1&0\\0&0&0&1
\end{array}\right)$$

for which I do not think you can come up with a matrix in $SL_4$ to be its preimage. But I have high confidence that this approach is incorrect so I would like to be pointed in a better direction.

Comment: $PGL_n$ is a quotient group of $GL_n$.

Comment: So $ SL_n=\{A| \det A=1\} $ and $PGL_n=\{A| A^TA=AA^T=I\}$?

Comment: Leaving the norm invariant $\|Av\|^2 = \|v\|^2 \implies A^* =A^{-1}$ is the orthogonal group $O_n(\mathbf{R})$ (the unitary group in the complex case). $PGL_n(\mathbf{R})$ is the linear group acting on projective space ie. $\lambda v$ is identified with $ v$  for any $\lambda \in \mathbf{R}^*$. Yes $SL_n(\mathbf{R})$ preserves the oriented volume (the determinant of sides of parallelepipeds). For $n$ odd the map $SL_n(\mathbf{R}) \to PGL_n(\mathbf{R})$ is surjective, but it doesn't work with $\mathbf{Q}$ (because $|\det(A)|^{1/n}$ isn't rational)

Comment: @reuns Thanks! Although I am confused as to what the proposed map is supposed to be. I am guessing you concluded n must be odd from some argument about orientation preserving? Or am I off-base?

Comment: The map $GL_n(k)\to PGL_n(k)$ is just $A \mapsto \{ \lambda A, \lambda \in k^*\}$ and the map $SL_n(k)\to PGL_n(k)$ is the same since $SL_n$ is a subgroup of $GL_n$. For $k = \mathbf{R}$ and $n$ odd I just took $A \in GL_n(\mathbf{R})$ and set $B = |\det(A)|^{-1/n} A, |\det(B)| = 1 $ so that $\det(B)= \pm 1$ and $B$ or $-B \in SL_n(\mathbf{R})$. By definition $A, B,-B$ are equal in $PGL_n(\mathbf{R})$. When $k = \mathbf{Q}$ it doesn't work because $|\det(A)|^{-1/n}\not \in \mathbf{Q}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For odd $n$ the canonical homomorphism is such a surjection.

For even $n$, there is no continuous surjective homomorphism because the left-hand group is connected and the second is not.

Actually there is no surjective homomorphism at all, because the left-hand group is generated by 1-parameter subgroups, hence has no nontrivial homomorphism to a group of order 2 (or to any finite group).

For $\mathbf{Q}$, the latter argument adapts while the conclusion is different: there is no surjective homomorphism $\mathrm{SL}_n(\mathbf{Q})\to\mathrm{PGL}_n(\mathbf{Q})$ for any $n\ge 2$. Because the latter is generated by additive 1-parameter subgroups, it has no non-trivial homomorphism to any finite group. On the other hand the determinant map $\mathrm{GL}_n(\mathbf{Q}\to\mathbf{Q}^*$ induces a surjective homomorphism $\mathbf{PGL}_n(\mathbf{Q})\to\mathbf{Q}^*/(\mathbf{Q}^*)^n$, and the latter group surjects onto $\mathbf{Z}/n\mathbf{Z}$.

Comment: For $n=2$ you meant $SL_2(\mathbf{Q})$ is generated by the $4$ subgroups ${\scriptstyle\begin{pmatrix} 1 & b \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}},{\scriptstyle\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ c & 1 \end{pmatrix}}$, ${\scriptstyle\begin{pmatrix} |a| & 0 \\ 0 & |a|^{-1} \end{pmatrix}}$, $\pm 1$ ?

Comment: No, I mean that it's only generated by the first two (upper and lower unipotent).